# Camel route-testing using adviceWith with OnException definitions

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I have a very simple Camel route definition which just includes some OnException predicates to handle respective exceptions and some log-statements.

```
from("hazelcast:seda:someQueue")
    .id("someQueueID")
    .onException(CustomException.class)
        .handled(true)
        .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "custom exception noticed")
    .end()
    .onException(IOException.class, FileNotFoundException.class)
        .asyncDelayedRedelivery()
        .redeliveryDelay(3*1000*60) // 3 Minutes
        .maximumRedeliveries(3)
        .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "io exception noticed")
    .end()
    .onException(Exception.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "general exception noticed")
    .end()

    .log("Starting route")
    .bean(TestBean.class)
    .log("Finished route");
```

The bean itself is simple too, it just checks a header parameter and throws an appropriate exception

```
public class TestBean
{
    @Handler
    public void checkData(@Headers final Map<String, Object> headers)
            throws CustomException, IOException, Exception
    {
        Integer testVal = (Integer)headers.get("TestValue");
        if (0 == testVal)
            throw new CustomException("CustomException");
        else if (1 == testVal)
            throw new IOException("IOException");
        else
            throw new Exception("Exception");
    }
}
```

As this test-setup is just a small part of a larger project it may sound silly to do it like presented here, but the core intend is to modify the redeliveryDelay at test time as a "forced" IOException will not need to wait 3 minutes and therefore, to speed up unit tests a bit, the redelivery delay could be reduced to like 10 ms.

In order to achieve this my test-method does the following:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = OnExceptionRouteTest.ContextConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class OnExceptionRouteTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport
{
    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext()
    {
        return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ContextConfig.class)
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class ContextConfig extends CamelConfiguration
    {
        @Override
        protected void setupCamelContext(CamelContext camelContext) throws Exception
        {
            super.setupCamelContext(camelContext);
            camelContext.addComponent("hazelcast", new StubComponent());
            // some other unnecessary stuff
        }

        @Override
        public List<RouteBuilder> routes()
        {
            final List<RouteBuilder> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new OnExceptionRoute());
            return list;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    public void testIOException()
    {
        context.getRouteDefinition("someQueueID")
                .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() 
                 {
                     @Override
                     public void configure() throws Exception
                     {
                         this.weaveByType(OnExceptionDefinition.class)
                             .selectIndex(1)
                             .replace()
                                 .onException(IOException.class, FileNotFound.class)
                                     .asyncDelayedRedelivery()
                                     .redeliveryDelay(10)
                                     .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                                     .log("modified io exception noticed")
                                     .to("mock:ioError")
                                 .end();
                          ...
                          mockEndpoints();
                     }
                });
        context.start();
        MockEndpoint ioErrorEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:ioError");
        ...
        ioErrorEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        ...

        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("TestValue", new Integer(1));
        template.sendBodyAndHeaders("hazelcast:seda:someQueue", new Object(), headers);

        ...
        ioErrorEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        ...
    }
}
```

Here the test just replaces the onException segment of the IOException to first reduce the redelivery delay from 3 minutes to 10 ms and adds a mock endpoint at the end. However when I try to run the unit test I'll get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The output must be added as top-level on the route. Try moving OnException[[class java.io.IOException, class java.io.FileNotFoundException] -> []] to the top of route.
```

However, the examples in the [official documentation](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html), as far as I understood them correctly, are very similar. I also tried to lookup the exception definition via a defined ID predicate and its corresponding method `weaveById()` or via the `weaveByToString()` method but with no other result. I also tried to remove the exception definition via `weaveByType(OnExceptionDefinition.class).selectIndex(1).remove();` and add the OnException part via `weaveAddFirst().onException(...).async...;` but with the same result.

Appending a mocked error endpoint, however, is possible via f.e. `weaveByToString("Log[io exception noticed]").after().to("mock:ioError");`

So any tips for modifying onException blocks or the redeliveryDelay for unit tests are more than welcome.

---

@Edit: I also tried now to move the onException declarations above the route definition (`from(...)`) as suggested by the exception message and this was also the preferred case in Camel's [exception samples](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html). On doing this, however, all tests (even the working ones) fail as of a `NullPointerException` on `context.getRouteDefinition("someQueueID").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {... });` as obviously the route itself can't be found anymore. I doubt that this is an IntelliJ issue as both classes are within the same project and therefore a modification of the route should be visible to the test-class.

Camel version in use: 2.13.0, IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2

---

@Edit2: For some reason `context.getRouteDefinitions("someQueueID")` returns null if the OnException elements are defined outside of the `from` block, whereas the general route can be obtained via `context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0)` - though, the exception stating that the OnException part needs to be added as top-level element remains.

Comment: Another option is to make the redeliveryDelay (and perhaps various other settings) a property, and then have a production properties file + a test properties file, with differing values to suit your needs in each environment.

Comment: @SteveHarrington Although your suggestion with injecting property values into these fields works, this does not solve the core issue for adviceWith in conjunction with onException blocks in my opinion. However, I would like to accept your suggestion as an answer if you are willing to post an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using the Java DSL, the id of the route is set using the `.routeId()` method, not `.id()` as you have coded above. That may help with your `adviceWith` concerns.

Instead of hard-coding the retry delay, a better approach would be to make the delay configurable using properties. Check out the documentation around the method `useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent()` on your `CamelSpringTestSupport` class.

**EDIT**

You don't have to weave the `onException` clause, simply state a new one. Here's a complete example:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithRouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;

public class DummyTest extends CamelTestSupport{
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                from("direct://start")
                    .routeId("myroute")
                    .onException(Exception.class)
                        .id("myException")
                        .continued(true)
                    .end()
                    .throwException(new Exception())
                    .to("mock:end");
            }
        };
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void doTest() throws Exception{
        context.getRouteDefinition("myroute").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                context.getRouteDefinition("myroute")
                    .onException(Exception.class).setBody(constant("adviceWith")).continued(true);
            }});
        context.start();
        template.sendBody("direct://start", "original");
        String bodyAtEndOfExchange = getMockEndpoint("mock:end")
                .getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody(String.class);
        assertEquals("adviceWith", bodyAtEndOfExchange);        
        context.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already figured out the issue regarding `.id(...)` and `.routeId(...)` but thank you for pointing it out here as I did not update the post since then. I also configured the delay via properties as already suggested by @SteveHarrington. While this fixed the issue of the test-specific deleay, the actual topic though still remains - how to advice an onException block properly? Of course, `inOnly` and `to` can be caught using interceptors, but what if we want to add something in the middle of the road and don't use ids. Not sure if Camel 2.15+ now comes with better support, have to try it again

Comment: For the next person: I was getting `NullPointerException`s in my unit tests (using Spring Boot + Camel based application configuration) whenever I would add in an `onException` statement at the top of my route configuration. I didn't realize that I was setting the wrong _id_ in the route (i.e. I was using `.id()` and not `.routeId()`). Thank you.