# Camel adviceWith for ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

I need to test my Camel Exception handler:

```
@Configuration
public class RouteConfiguration extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class).
                handled(true).
                log("HttpOperationFailedException: ${exception}").
                onExceptionOccurred(myRestExceptionProcessor).id("myRestExceptionProcessor").end();

         from("direct:myPrettyRoute").routeId("myPrettyRoute");//lots of routing here       

    }
}
```

I'm trying to add adviceWith after myRestExceptionProcessor, but can't find a way.

```
public class MyExceptionRoutingTest {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext context;

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        if (ServiceStatus.Stopped.equals(context.getStatus())) {
            log.info("prepare mocks endpoint");

            List<OnExceptionDefinition> ed = context.getErrorHandlerBuilder().getErrorHandlers(context.getRoutes().get(0).getRouteContext());
            //FAILS, because context.getRoutes() is empty at the moment
            //even if it wasn't, getErrorHandlerBuilder() is deprecated
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add something like this for the exceptionHandler definition:

```
    .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                weaveById("myExceptionProcessor").after().to(myResultEndpoint).id("myResponseEndpoint");
            }
        });
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737250/camel-route-testing-using-advicewith-with-onexception-definitions) already 4 years ago and haven't found a working solution so far. According to Camel developers they rather argument that business logic (the thing to test so to say) should not be handled in exception handlers. If you'd maintain a `to("some-component:...")` inside your exception handler you might try to intercept this with `interceptSendToEndpoint("some-component:*).skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().to("mock:error")` though

Comment: @Roman Vottner, unfortunately, I don't have endpoints there. Just some processing & marshaling. I've seen a workaround: add .to(direct:myErrorhandlerFinish) at the end of handler & create an according route. By it looks very dirty to me.

Comment: According to the [release notes of Camel 2.22](http://camel.apache.org/camel-2220-release.html) they `Fixed using AdviceWith and using weave methods on onException etc. not working.` This fix therefore should allow to weave onException blocks now.

Comment: It seems this is broken again in Camel 3

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand if you want to test your error handler (`onException` block) or just your `myRestExceptionProcessor`, but from a Camel perspective these are two kinds of tests:

1. **Routing-Tests** to test your **routing logic** and make sure that **messages are correctly routed** under various conditions that could happen in the route. This is the kind of tests you write with the Camel Testkit (that offers adviceWith and much more).
2. Classic **unit tests** to test an isolated Bean, Processor or anything else that is used in the route to implement **business logic**. This kind of test is done with JUnit, TestNG or other classic unit test frameworks, it has nothing to do with Camel. **Do not try to test such components with Camel Route tests** since it is much more complicated than in a unit test!

So, if you want to test your routing when an error occurs you **throw the needed error** in your route test to trigger the error handler. If you use a dependency injection framework like Spring this is easy since you can inject a test Bean that throws an error instead of a real Bean used in the route.

To add a Mock endpoint at the end of a route, use [adviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html)

```
.adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        weaveAddLast().to("mock:error");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit. Feel free to extend your question to elaborate your problem a bit more.

Comment: The full test-case was: to call route - emulate exception - make sure it's caught and processed correctly, check result. Testing only processor in isolation is too abridged.

Comment: I added to my answer how to append something to a route

Comment: Thanks, weaveAddLast() was usefull, but not for receiving response from errorhandler. It's also skipped if exception occurs (mockResultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied()) fails

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the trick as follows, without changing the route:

```
//entry point of the route is invoked here
Exchange send = myProducer.withBody("body is here").send(); 
HttpOperationFailedException exception = send.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class);
String responseBody = exception.getResponseBody();
//recieved result and made assertions
assert responseBody != null; // any other assertions
```

Comment: Using Javas assertions may be misleading for testing as they are only activated if `-ea` (enable assertions) is passed at application startup. On missing to provide that option no failure will be reported. Usually it is safer to use JUnit's `assertThat` or any of the other asserts provided by that framework (or other frameworks like TestNG, AssertJ, ...). While your solution does solve your actual problem, it bypasses the actual question of testing exceptions through advicing an existing route